# How to extract icons from an executable?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, icons, registry

I'm working on a personal project in which I'd like to give the opportunity to the user to browse and work with the registry (the HKCU key) just like he would do with regedit.exe.

Everything works fine, but I'd like now to somehow extract the icons associated with the registry values.
Does anyone has an idea on how I can achieve something like this?

Example of Icons I'd like to get:

[image: Example of Icons I'd like to get]

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking us to tell you how to swipe copyrighted resources from the Windows operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ExtractIconEx()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069(v=vs.85).aspx) to extract those icons from `regedit.exe`.

> Note that `regedit.exe` can be found in both `Windows` and 
>   `Windows\System32` directories. Here, I assume it's under `Windows`.

Win API declarations:

```
  [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern uint ExtractIconEx(string lpszFile, int nIconIndex, [Out] IntPtr[] phiconLarge, [Out] IntPtr[] phiconSmall, [In] uint nIcons);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  public static extern int DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
```

`ExtractIconEx()` is first called with null parameters, to get the number of icons the file contains.
With this information, we retrieve the Small and Large Icons handles in 2 arrays and create a GDI+ Icon from those handles using [`Icon.FromHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle).

```
string icnSource = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "regedit.exe");

uint icnNumber = ExtractIconEx(icnSource, -1, null, null, 1);

if (icnNumber > 0)
{
    IntPtr[] phiconLarge = new IntPtr[icnNumber];
    IntPtr[] phiconSmall = new IntPtr[icnNumber];
    ExtractIconEx(icnSource, 0, phiconLarge, phiconSmall, icnNumber);

    Icon[] iconsmall = new Icon[icnNumber];
    Icon[] iconlarge = new Icon[icnNumber];

    for (int x = 0; x < icnNumber; x++)
    {
        if (phiconLarge != null)
        {
            iconlarge[x] = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(phiconLarge[x]).Clone();
            DestroyIcon(phiconLarge[x]);
        }
        if (phiconSmall != null)
        {
            iconsmall[x] = (Icon)Icon.FromHandle(phiconSmall[x]).Clone();
            DestroyIcon(phiconSmall[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can transform an Icon into a GDI+ Bitmap, if necessary, using [`Icon.ToBitmap()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.tobitmap).

**These, number 3 and 4, are the Icons you are looking for**:

```
pictureBox1.Image = iconsmall[3].ToBitmap();
pictureBox2.Image = iconsmall[4].ToBitmap();
```